# Error while trying to create a 2D dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have to create a 2D dynamic array of structures and read those structures from a binary file. The compiler gives me the following error: `"error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'S_Apartament {aka struct <anonymous>}' from type 'size_t {aka unsigned int}'"`., when trying to access the elements of the array. Code:

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("Block.bin", "rb");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
        fclose(f);
        exit(1);
    }
    S_Apartament Flats;
    unsigned int floor=0, flats_per_floor=0; // Declaring dimensons of the array
    fread(&floor,sizeof(unsigned),1,f);
    fread(&flats_per_floor,sizeof(unsigned),1,f);
    S_Apartament **ptr = (S_Apartament **)malloc(sizeof(S_Apartament*) * floor);//Declaring an array of pointers
    for (int i = 0; i <  floor; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = (S_Apartament*)malloc(sizeof(S_Apartament)*flats_per_floor);//Each pointer in the array becomes an array of structures.
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <  floor; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < flats_per_floor; j++)
        {
            ptr[i][j]=fread(&Flats,sizeof(S_Apartament),1,f);//Trying to access the array, in order to read from the binary file.
        }
    }
    fclose(f);


    return 0;
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
   unsigned int Flat_ID;
   unsigned int count_Rooms;
   unsigned int count_Adults;
   unsigned int count_Children;
   char Family_Surname[20];
   unsigned int day_of_entry;
   unsigned int month_of_entry;
   unsigned int year_of_entry;
   float rent;
   int occupancy;
}S_Apartament;
#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ptr[i][j]=fread(&Flats,sizeof(S_Apartament),1,f);
```

`fread` returns the `size_t` type (the number of items read or written), but in your code `ptr[i][j]` has the type: `S_Apartament`.

Your program raise error because you try to assign a integer value (return of `fread`) to an `S_Apartament` value (`ptr[i][j]`)

Answer (score 0):

you can try "S_Apartament **ptr = (S_Apartament **)malloc(sizeof(S_Apartament**) * floor)". sizeof (S_Apartament**) is not sizeof (S_Apartament*).